# Need to set Password complexity for root in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, password

When i tried to set the password complexity by adding the values in /etc/pam.d/common-password and /etc/security/pwquality.conf. I have set the minlen=8, for other user it works fine for root user its not working.

How i can set the minlen=8 for root user.

Comment: Reminder: root can change the config anytime.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_pwquality):

> `enforce_for_root`
>
> The module will return error on failed check even if the user changing the password is root. This option is off by default which means that just the message about the failed check is printed but root can change the password anyway.

Simply add `enforce_for_root` to a line by it self in `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`.

Note that root can bypass this more or less at will by injecting their password hash. There's ultimately few things that stops root from ignoring configuration on Linux.

Comment: i have added enforce_for_root in /etc/pam.d/common-password, still root password length was not accepting.    pam_pwquality.so retry=3 enforce_for_root

Comment: Not sure I grok your comment?

Comment: Tell me where i need to add enforce_for_root.

Comment: Maybe reading the provided link could help?

Comment: @Thamizh answer updated :)