# password complexity using /etc/pam.d/common-password

Tags: password, security

so I am testing setting up password complixity on ubuntu 22.04 and it looks like we use /etc/pam.d/common-password to modify/add fields.  So from the file, I changed the line 25 from:

**password  requisite           pam_pwquality.so retry=3**

TO:

**password requisite pam_pwquality.so minlen=12 minclass=4 remember=15 reject_username**

After rebooting the server and creating a new user to test, the following modules work: minlen, minclass and reject_username.  However, it seems the remember module does not work. Any ideas?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to set Password complexity for root in ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479361/need-to-set-password-complexity-for-root-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enforce a password complexity policy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244115/how-do-i-enforce-a-password-complexity-policy)

Comment: They do not work and is not relevant to my question but thanks.

Comment: If anyone else can chime in, that would be greatly appreciated.